# how to evaluate expression in nested list

Tags: r, lapply

I want to iterate a function over all columns in a data frame with different arguments for the function for each column.
I am trying to do this through a nested lapply.

The result however is not what I expect, I expected to pass the value down from first lapply to the second one, but as shown in the result below, the second lapply prints "var" without replacing it with "var1" etc.

How should I fix it?

```
# sample data frame
 df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 100),
                 var1 = rnorm(100),
                 var2 = rnorm(100),
                 var3 = rnorm(100))

# list 1
var.list <- setdiff(names(df),"date")

# list 2
pen.list <-  c("mean(df[[var]])", "log(mean(df[[var]]))", "log(mean(df[[var]]))^2", "mean(df[[var]])^2/2")


lapply(var.list, function(var){
  lapply(pen.list, function(pen){
    print(var)
    print(pen)
    plot(cpt.mean(df[[var]],penalty = "Manual", method = "PELT", pen.value = noquote(pen)))
  })
  })

#Result
[1] "var1"
[1] "mean(df[[var]])"
[1] "var1"
[1] "log(mean(df[[var]]))"
[1] "var1"
[1] "log(mean(df[[var]]))^2"
[1] "var1"
[1] "mean(df[[var]])^2/2"
[1] "var2"
[1] "mean(df[[var]])"
[1] "var2"
[1] "log(mean(df[[var]]))"
[1] "var2"
[1] "log(mean(df[[var]]))^2"
[1] "var2"
[1] "mean(df[[var]])^2/2"
[1] "var3"
[1] "mean(df[[var]])"
[1] "var3"
[1] "log(mean(df[[var]]))"
[1] "var3"
[1] "log(mean(df[[var]]))^2"
[1] "var3"
[1] "mean(df[[var]])^2/2"
```

Comment: What is `df_today` in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we need to use a string interpolation

```
library(stringr)
lapply(var.list, function(var){
  lapply(pen.list, function(pen){
    print(var)
    print(str_replace(pen, 'var', sprintf('"%s"', var) ))
    #plot(cpt.mean(df_today[[var]],penalty = "Manual", method = "PELT", pen.value = noquote(pen)))
  })
  })
```

-output

```
[1] "var1"
[1] "mean(df_today[[\"var1\"]])"
[1] "var1"
[1] "log(mean(df_today[[\"var1\"]]))"
[1] "var1"
[1] "log(mean(df_today[[\"var1\"]]))^2"
[1] "var1"
[1] "mean(df_today[[\"var1\"]])^2/2"
[1] "var2"
[1] "mean(df_today[[\"var2\"]])"
[1] "var2"
[1] "log(mean(df_today[[\"var2\"]]))"
[1] "var2"
[1] "log(mean(df_today[[\"var2\"]]))^2"
[1] "var2"
[1] "mean(df_today[[\"var2\"]])^2/2"
[1] "var3"
[1] "mean(df_today[[\"var3\"]])"
[1] "var3"
[1] "log(mean(df_today[[\"var3\"]]))"
[1] "var3"
[1] "log(mean(df_today[[\"var3\"]]))^2"
[1] "var3"
[1] "mean(df_today[[\"var3\"]])^2/2"
...
```

---

Just to confirm that it works by `eval`uation

```
df_today <- df
lapply(var.list, function(var){
  lapply(pen.list, function(pen){
    print(var)
    eval(parse(text = str_replace(pen, 'var', sprintf('"%s"', var) )))
  })
  })
```

-output

```
[1] "var1"
[1] "var1"
[1] "var1"
[1] "var1"
[1] "var2"
[1] "var2"
[1] "var2"
[1] "var2"
[1] "var3"
[1] "var3"
[1] "var3"
[1] "var3"
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] -0.02421389

[[1]][[2]]
[1] NaN

[[1]][[3]]
[1] NaN

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 0.0002931563


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 0.0746259

[[2]][[2]]
[1] -2.595268

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 6.735414

[[2]][[4]]
[1] 0.002784513


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0.01060897

[[3]][[2]]
[1] -4.546055

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 20.66662

[[3]][[4]]
[1] 5.627514e-05
```